# How do I limit privileges to a user in a express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a webpage which has a form which allows users to add comments to the page to give feedback.

https://express-chat-comment-ap.herokuapp.com/feedback

You'll notice a user can delete comments, not only their own comments, but all of them.

So my question is, how would you limit those privileges to only that current user?

There is a major piece to all of this which is the web page is being integrated to a website which has a user login/user account already.

Also do I have to do any research regarding what back end their using now? Or can I keep this all encapsulated with Express/Node?

What packages should I use?

Where do I start?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You must have an authenticated and logged in userID for each user that your server authenticates and understands.  Each comment must be saved with the userID of the creator and you must be able to retrieve that from your data store.

Then, your server can check who the user is that is attempting an operation (probably from a logged in cookie that accompanies the request), what the operation that is being attempted and decide if that operation is allowed by that user.  For example, if the user logged in is "Bob" and they try to delete a comment from "Alice", then the server will refuse to carry out that operation.

And, your UI in the web page can not offer operations that are not allowed (though the server must always check anyway).  So, if you have a delete button in the comment, you would only show that button on comments that belong to the current user.

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the horse before the cart.  This isn't really a "Node/Express" question; you're not going to solve it at the Javascript level.

Instead, your main question is actually "How do I do 'security'?"

More specifically: "How do I 'authenticate' users?"  "How do I grant access?"  "How do I *prevent* access?"  And so on...

SUGGESTIONS:

[User Authentication with the MEAN Stack](https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/)

[MySQL Authentication using Passport](https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84)

[OAuth 2 Single Sign on Authentication with Passport](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/social-authentication-for-nodejs-apps-with-passport--cms-21618)

[Node.js: Token based authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)

[Heroku: Managing Organization Users and Application Access](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/org-users-access)